# fetch facebook user's friends with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a new comer of StackOverFlow. As title, I 'd like to pick a subset of the user's friends, and I have tried that in the Graph API Explorer with `→ /v2.1/   me?fields=friends`. However it return an empty json named data and the total count of the user's friends. What did I miss?? Below is my test in the facebook Graph API explorer.. ! Here comes the result in the graph api explorer.

```
{
    "friends": {
        "data": [
            ], 
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 15
        }
        }, 
    "id": "585768444863088"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also just use `/me/friends` instead, but the empty array is correct. You only get those friends who authorized your App too, you don´t get every friend anymore since end of April 2014 (v2.0 of the Graph API).

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> 3. /me/friends returns the user's friends who are also using your app

There are ways to get the whole friendlist like [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.1) and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends, but those endpoints are supposed to get used for very specific tasks (for inviting in games and for tagging).

Comment: Er...since April 2014. I started add this feature to my app a month ago. What I found here about it are out of date. So is there should still be some other way to get user's friend list ?

Comment: i´ve edited my answer, check it out. apart from that, there is no other way. this is for privacy reasons, a user who does not use your app should not be listed.

Comment: T T I found it ../me/taggable_friends will do. Thanks A LOT~~

Comment: I C ~ The user I mentioned is the user who log in my app ~

Comment: taggable_friends can only be used for tagging people and will not be approved for anything else